# Curl, simple php login response to form

Tags: php, html, linux, http, curl

I'm trying to create a simple php login page, for testing purposes.

Basically, it just needs username, password and submit.

I have found this easy code and it works fine:

```
<?php
session_start(); $username = $password = $userError = $passError = '';
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
  $username = $_POST['username']; $password = $_POST['password'];
  if($username === 'admin' && $password === 'password'){
    $_SESSION['login'] = true; header('LOCATION:wherever.php'); die();
  }
  if($username !== 'admin' || $password !== 'pass')  echo "Invalid";
   else echo "Valid";

}
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
     <title>Login</title>
     <style type='text.css'>
       @import common.css;
     </style>
   </head>
<body>
  <form name='input' action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' method='post'>
    <label for='username'></label><input type='text' value='$username' id='username' name='username' />
    <div class='error'>$userError</div>
    <label for='password'></label><input type='password' value='$password' id='password' name='password' />
    <div class='error'>$passError</div>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='sub' />
  </form>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='common.js'></script>
</body>
</html>";
?>
```

Now the purpose of this page should be this:

On submitting "admin", "pass" return "Valid". Anything else, return "Invalid".

If I click submit and login, Valid/Invalid appear accordingly on top.

The problem is that when I try to get the same output with curl (http post?), it **fails to print any.**

**I have tried this, according to all the answers I could find it's correct:**

```
curl --data "username=admin&password=pass&sub=Submit" http://altervista.mypagegoeshere.org/index.php -o /root/Desktop/out.txt
```

But it shows no output.

**Other answers suggested replacing `--data` with `-F`

This action still prints neither "Valid" nor "Invalid", but does print the whole html code of the page.**

Curling just the address gived back all the html, so that's correct.

**I need the curl input to return `Valid`, or `Invalid`.**

What am I doing wrong?

According to the answers here on SO and to https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html
the curl command I wrote is correct.

I am running this from the ubuntu terminal, I don't know if that's helpful.

Comment: I tried it and got the expected output, `Valid` followed by the HTML of the page.

Comment: You'll get no output if you use `&password=password` instead of `&password=pass`, because of `die()`.